# Failed called Docusign API for getTemplate lsit in the production site?

Tags: templates, docusignapi, production

I’m making a call to the APis to get the template list of a folder it works, perfectly in the demo site for developers (sandbox) but when I switch to production site it gives me an error saying that username or password is invalid, which is not true, actually before that call to get templates I’m calling the login using the same credentials and I get the right accounted, so the user and password are ok, do you know what’s going on?Is there any account restriction in the production site to call get templates?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to authenticate with the Login Information call but other calls are failing, it's likely that you're making your GetTemplates call to the incorrect server. Are you using the Base URL from your login_information call in the GetTemplates call?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm making both calls to the same production serevr: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi

Comment: demo.docusign.net is not the production site. If you have passed Go-Live then see [Post Go-Live guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/guides/post-go-live)